# Duplicate item show up in spotlight and thumbnail not showing

Tags: ios, spotlight, nsuseractivity

I'm trying to using `NSUserActivity`, `Core Spotlight APIs` and web markup at the same time.

So based on the suggestions given in [App Search Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/CombiningAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH10-SW1)

> If you’re using all three APIs, it works well to use the URL of the
>   relevant webpage as the value for uniqueIdentifier,
>   relatedUniqueIdentifier, and webpageURL.

This is how I created the item:

```
NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"com.test.product"];
activity.title = self.detailModel.title;
activity.userInfo = @{ @"id" : self.detailModel.productId };
activity.eligibleForHandoff = NO;
activity.eligibleForPublicIndexing = YES;
activity.eligibleForSearch = YES;
activity.webpageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self shareUrl]];

activity.contentAttributeSet.contentDescription = self.detailModel.proDesc;
activity.contentAttributeSet.title = self.detailModel.title;
activity.contentAttributeSet.thumbnailData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
activity.contentAttributeSet.relatedUniqueIdentifier = [self shareUrl];

CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *attrSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL];
attrSet.title = self.detailModel.title;
attrSet.contentDescription = self.detailModel.proDesc;
attrSet.thumbnailData = activity.contentAttributeSet.thumbnailData;
attrSet.relatedUniqueIdentifier = [self shareUrl];

CSSearchableItem *searchableItem = [[CSSearchableItem alloc] initWithUniqueIdentifier:[self shareUrl] domainIdentifier:@"com.test.product" attributeSet:attrSet];
[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:@[ searchableItem ] completionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        DDLogError(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        DDLogInfo(@"Core Spotlight indexed");
    }
  }];
  }
}];

self.systemUserActivity = activity;
[self.systemUserActivity becomeCurrent];
```

But when I tried to search in spotlight, there are two problems:

- Duplicated items show up, one from activity and the other from spotlight index
- Both items only show with the app icon instead of the image I set